# What do I do with automatic redirects to CSS/JS resources during a JMeter Test?

Tags: jmeter

So I am very new to JMeter and trying to create a simple test for a front end application.

After logging in, my application re-directs me to a HTTP GET called 'Dashboard' - this loads all the front end JS and CSS and processes it in the browser. My JMeter test also does the same (see screenshot) But this process is 3 times slower in JMeter than in a real browser. 
[image]

So my question is,

1. Should I even be testing the load time of JS/CSS in JMeter? If not, how can I re-configure my test so that it doesn't load these things
2. Why is the response time in JMeter slower than the browser for this particular GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should as long as the JS/CSS are coming from the same source as the main content. If your application is downloading JS from 3rd-party services and CSS from some CDN - you can omit this. If some scripts /styles are coming from 3rd-party services and some are local - you need to test only "local" ones, the others need to be filtered out on [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) level
2. Most probably this is due to [Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), normally browsers download these scripts and styles only once, on subsequent calls no actual request is being made, scripts and styles are being returned from the browser cache which is much faster so consider adding a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan and delete browsing history - this way you should get more or less the same timings

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)